# Is "less than or equal to" sometimes written with two lines?

Tags: notation

I'm reading this research paper and they have the equation like this (0 ≤ λ ≤ 1) however the less than or equal to part has two lines, see screenshot here: http://prntscr.com/s5o0do

I just wanted to ask and confirm that this is just another way of writing "less than or equal to" or if it had a different meaning.

Comment: IMO, it is only a notational variant; see [Inequality](Inequality (mathematics))

Comment: FYI, the version with an equals sign under < used to be standard, but at some point (1960s or 1970s?), the version with a single bar under the < started to become more common, and in the last two or three decades it's become nearly universally used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both signs have the same meaning. $\leq$ is actually the abbreviation of the version with the equality sign $\leqq$. $\leqslant$ is the third variant of it.